# How to wrap groups of strings in single quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to export elements of an array to strings but keep the single quotes around the elements. As you can see, exporting them to the `toString()` method outputs `Banana, Orange, Apple, Mango` but I need to have them like `'Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Mango'`.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var map = fruits.toString();

console.log(map);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Note that [`.toSource()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSource) will do this, although it has little support. You can also use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and replace the double quotes with single ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES6

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
// creates a new array containing: ["'Banana'", "'Orange'", "'Apple'", "'Mango'"]
var exportedFruits = fruits.map(fruit => "'" + fruit + "'");
console.log(exportedFruits.toString())
```

ES5

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
// creates a new array containing: ["'Banana'", "'Orange'", "'Apple'", "'Mango'"]
var exportedFruits = fruits.map(function(fruit){
  return "'" + fruit + "'";
});
console.log(exportedFruits.toString())
```

Comment: Can you explain what is going on here?

Comment: They are replacing each value in the array to the same value but with quotes on the ends `value => 'value'`.

Comment: Made an edit adding a comment, but @SpencerWieczorek just explained it ...

Comment: So what it the role of `fruit` at `fruits.map(fruit => "'" + fruit + "'")` ?

Comment: This is the current value iterated (like in a forEach) - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: `"'" + ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"].join("','") + "'"` could work but @MonaCoder was asking about the behavior of `.toString()`

Comment: @topheman Understand though that toString on arrays is special and you're just adding to your stack by calling toString(). The answer should be don't use it. Bake your noodle: https://jsfiddle.net/gw2tg8mu/

Answer (score 1):

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var result = "'" + fruits.join("','") + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can use jQuery's `map`.

JavaScript ES6/ES2015 also has a `Array.protytype.map` which works very similar.

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var res = $.map(arr, (function(val) {
  return "'" + val + "'";
  }));

console.log(res.join(","));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var map = fruits.map(myFun).toString();

console.log(map);
function myFun(val,i,array){
    return "'"+val+"'";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd pause on the Array.map solution. A map to do a join operation works of course, but is a bit heavy handed. Granted we're in system nano time on small sets, but it is perhaps significant in some settings where processing time is critical. Converting large datasets to comma delimited strings, such as with CSV export is a common case. Good old fashioned join is tough to beat.

//edited with new times based on array of strings:

ES6 Array.map: 18.2150 ms

ES5 Array.map: 21.7800 ms

join: 3.5750 ms

```js
var map, start, end, fruits;


fruits = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
 fruits.push(i.toString());
}

start = performance.now();
var exportedFruits = fruits.map(fruit => "'" + fruit + "'");
exportedFruits = exportedFruits.toString();
end = performance.now();
console.log((end - start).toFixed(4)+" ms");

start = performance.now();
var exportedFruits = fruits.map(function(fruit){
  return "'" + fruit + "'";
});
exportedFruits = exportedFruits.toString();
end = performance.now();
console.log((end - start).toFixed(4)+" ms");


start = performance.now();
map = "'" + fruits.join("','") +"'";
end = performance.now();
console.log((end - start).toFixed(4)+" ms");
```

Edit: I forgot to measure the toString operation on the first two.

Comment: You should `fruits.push(i.toString())` (to have strings in your array already, like the original use case), you'll have even better performances

Comment: After dong that, the final join method is reduced to 5 ms. thx.